# mediaelementjs ie9 fullscreen event

Tags: javascript, video, internet-explorer-9, mediaelement.js

I want to detect the `mediaelementjs` full screen event in `IE9`. I handle the event by subscribing to "fullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange". The problem is that clicking the fullscreen button on the video player in `IE9` opens in a new popup and no fullscreenchange is fired. Any ideas how to handle this event under `IE9`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediaelement simulates fullscreen for IE9 with opening the video in a pop up.So no "fullscreenchange" event is fired in IE9.In order to handle the pop up fullscreen we need to extend the "MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen" and MediaElementPlayer.prototype.exitFullScreen" functions.

Sample code:

```
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen_org =
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen;

MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen = function() {
  if((/MSIE 9.0/).test(navigator.userAgent)){
    // your code here
  }
  this.enterFullScreen_org();
}

// Same for the .exitFullScreen
```